# How to read and write to a python program through vb.net

Tags: .net, python, vb.net

I am currently making a GUI for Minecraft Coder Pack. MCP works off a system of batch files that launch python programs. I want to be able to read and write to these cmd windows throught vb.net. So that I can tell when a process has finished or to answer a yes, no question i nthe python program, with a gui from vb.net
An example of the batch launch code is

```
    @echo off
runtime\bin\python\python_mcp runtime\cleanup.py %*
pause
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to write from vb.net to a text file (input.txt, for example), then use "<" to use input.txt for input on the command line and ">" to send the command line output to another file (output.txt, for example). Then you can read output.txt from vb.net.

```
runtime\bin\python\python_mcp zruntime\cleanup.py %* < input.txt > output.txt
```